# Can I use stackoverflow English website to help me translate something?

Tags: discussion

I'm a beginner in English, and I'm translating some texts, can I use, english.stackoverflow website to post a part of all the text that I wrote, to ask people if there is any mistakes in my text?

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't. From the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq):

> But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - Proofreading ("are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified
>     ...
> - "How to improve my English?" (this is not constructive anyway)
> - Translation and non-English languages

Each SE site has a FAQ that, in the first question, states what is on- and off-topic for the site, and in this case your specific situation is explicitly named as off-topic.

Comment: But if you have enough reps, you can ask for help in chat.